# How do I loop through a javascript array of audio files?

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, for-loop, playlist

I have a small question about using an array containing Audio-sources (links) in a for loop.

This is my code, basically:

```
    var audio = new Audio();
    var playlist = new Array('sounds/song0.m4a', 'sounds/song1.m4a', 'sounds/song2.m4a');

        for (var i = 0; i <= playlist.length; i++){
    audio.src = (playlist[i]);
    audio.volume = 0.3;
    audio.loop = false;
    if (audio.ended = true)
        i++;

    if (i = 2) {
        i = 0;
    }
```

My console gives me an error on the audio.src = (playlist[i]); . Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended_%28Web_Audio%29) event

```
var audio = new Audio(),
    i = 0;
var playlist = new Array('http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/horse.mp3', 'http://demos.w3avenue.com/html5-unleashed-tips-tricks-and-techniques/demo-audio.mp3');

audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    i = ++i < playlist.length ? i : 0;
    console.log(i)
    audio.src = playlist[i];
    audio.play();
}, true);
audio.volume = 0.3;
audio.loop = false;
audio.src = playlist[0];
audio.play();
```

Comment: How should I implement this in my code? 
If I'd want to play the songs and loop it 1 - ended, next song: 2, ended, next song: 3, ended: loop restart to 1.

- EDIT: I think I got it to work, thank you!

Comment: Well, it seems it works to play, but when the song ends, it doesn't jump to the next one. How should I implement that?

Comment: @ArunPJohny,  how to do the exact same thing but delay the next song to play after previous ended? I'm making a game like Incredibox (http://www.incredibox.com/) and I need to have that musical measure like there. I'm using drag and drop to play sounds.